# Generalized Linear Model optional weights

Tags: generalized-linear-model, weighted-regression

In Introduction to General and Generalized Linear Models by H. Madsen & P. Thyregod, the ML estimator for $\beta$ is defined in eq. 4.42 (p.106) as
$$W(\beta) = \text{diag}\bigg\{\frac{w_i}{g'(\mu_i)^2V(\mu_i)}\bigg\}$$
According to Theorem 4.1 (p.104) the weights, $w_i$, are optional.

What is the purpose and effect of having weights?